# How to add custom query params in ReactNative Auth0 - /authorize url?

Tags: typescript, react-native, oauth-2.0, auth0

I need to add additional query parameters `&foo=bar` to the `/authorize` URL. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
const auth0 = new Auth0({
  clientId: 'xxx',
  domain: 'yyy',
});
```

And the login method looks like this

```
async loginWithAuth0(): Promise<Credentials | null> {
  try {
    const credentials: Credentials = await auth0.webAuth.authorize({
      scope: 'openid profile email offline_access',
    });
    return credentials;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error with Auth0 Login', error);
    return null;
  }
}
```

The auth0 library is generating/appending all required query parameters to the `/authorize` request, need a way to customize and add a few more.

Comment: Using fetch !? we can help you more if you show some part of your code or an exemple.

Comment: @ANDRIAMANAMPISOAA.M. updated question. Please take a look

Comment: Official Documentation: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/react-native